# VersionOne API Client vs .NET object Model

Tags: versionone

I'm creating a dashboard which will display data from many sources including VersionOne.

The basic high level data which I plan to display in dashboard is :

sprint burndown chart 
release burndown chart
open/closed stories for current sprint
etc...

All the data is basically for reporting purposes.

My confusion here is which of the two techniques to be used for development.

I remember reading in one of the forums  that .NET object model is basically used to create assets and not all reporting metrics can be obtained using .NET object model and we have to use api client.

Any information before I start my design and coding will be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Dilip M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Object Model libraries for both Java and .NET are in sunset now. For support reasons, I recommend against the Object Model. Also, the main reason for sunsetting the Object Model was poor performance that would require significant, breaking changes to fix. So for performance reasons, I also recommend against using the Object Model.

I do recommend using our [query.v1](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Tour_of_query.v1) endpoint with standard HTTP and JSON libraries. There are a number of recipes that already explain how to extract the data, including one for [burndown data](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Query_for_Burndown_Data).

You didn't mention whether you were an on-premise or hosted customer. On-premise customers have the option of accessing a [datamart](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/Data_Mart) using SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure whether on-premise means hosted in our corporate environment. Our setup includes accessing the url and providing a domain user credentials to access the V1.

Comment: Yes. By on-premise I mean hosted in your corporate environment. When your URL has v1host.com in it, then we would call that "on demand", not "on premise".